# Android studio generating asset files

Tags: android, android-studio

Ih Guys!

I have made some assets for notifications and adaptive launcher icons using the new Image Asset option in android studio.

I have noticed there is an option for "Action bar and Tab Icons"... Could someone please explain where these icons are used in the code and where they will be displayed in the app.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action bar is the place where your toolbar is present
[image]

In the above picture `Page Title` is the action bar. And the heart and search icons are action bar icons. Android generates assets for this from `Action bar and Tab Icons` of required size.

Read more [about Creating app icons with Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) it covers everything about `Action bar and tab icons` and other icons as well!

Comment: If i don't use an action bar in my app do i need to bother with the Action bar and Tab Icons?

Comment: No!  `Action bar and Tab Icons` will generate icons for only action bars.If you don't use them don't generate them!\

Comment: So what actually are tab icons?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a link where you can read about the tab icons and other types of icons and where to use them! link: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Comment: Ok... I do use a tab view but the icons are made in flutter... i dont think i need to generate any icons.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Action Bar is the thing at the top of your app (usually with a title). You can also add a menu to the Action Bar, this is where icons are used.

Comment: I havent added an action bar to my app will this still get used?